# How to login to website from an app, then display data from the webpage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, url

I'm making an iPhone app in which you need to supply your username and password. It then needs to login to a website, and extract some text from the webpage that the user would be redirected to (if using a web browser) - this text would then need to be displayed. I have both URLs: the one to log in, and the "homepage" (first page seen when logged in).

If I type into my web browser:

https://[rest of URL]/[form name].asp?username=[my username]&password=[my password]

it redirects me to my "homepage". If I had logged in before, the website would remember that I was logged in and therefore I could go straight to the "homepage" without having to re-check my credentials.

How should I go about doing this? I'm quite new to `NSURL` and `NSURLRequest` so I have no idea where so start, given that there aren't really any tutorials that helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this block code:

```
NSString *urlAsString = @" http:// www.apple.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAsString];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                   queue:queue
                        completionHandler: ^(NSURLResponse *response,
                                             NSData *data,
                                             NSError *error) {
  if([data length] > 0 && error == nil) {
    NSString *html = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                           encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"HTML = %@", html);
  } else if([data length] == 0 && error == nil) {
    NSLog(@"Nothing was downloaded.");
  } else if (error != nil) {
    NSLog(@" Error happened = %@", error);
  }
}];
```

Comment: The data is there, but the HTML string is (null)... Any ideas?

Comment: I made some revisions to my answer (deleted some spaces). If you are getting a null HTML string that means the HTML string did not get initialized. That can only happen if there was an error. What error message was displayed?

Comment: If I open the saved file, it opens in Chrome! It's the webpage, but without any images. Oh and btw the webpage is ".asp", I don't know if that matters when loading the string...? The whole file starts with <html> and ends with </html>

Comment: OK on what you need to do. Coming back to my previous question, what error message are you getting if the HTML string is null?

Comment: I'm not getting any error message... It's also (null). The problem is, I now need to "click on a link" on that homepage, and it'll take me to another asp-webpage. Thing is, when I do it in my code, it says my session "timed out" and I'd have to login again. Any ideas? The text I need to obtain is on that second webpage.

Comment: There seems to be more at play here than what you have described so far. If you are not getting an error message than, to me knowledge at least, you should have something in the HTML string. If you need to "click on a link", why not go to that URL in the first place? If it is a dynamic link then you need to rethink your approach. No idea on the timed out message. Could be your code or the web server code. Baring any additional in depth info,  I do not think I can help you any further on this issue. Sorry.

Comment: I got it to work! All I had to do was submit the second webpage's "form" in the same way as above, just after I'd submitted the first form, and the html it gave me is both an NSString AND the stuff I was originally looking for! Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Thats a common scenerio, just post a request and asynchronously get the response, see code below

```
  -(void)Login
    {
        NSURL* url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"https://[rest of URL]/[form name].asp"];
        NSMutableURLRequest* request =
            [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        NSString* postString = @"username=[my userna

me]&password=[my password]";
            [request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncodi

ng]];

        NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

        [connection start];
    }








    -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
    {
        //assign data to your property, this is the result of the post
    }

    - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
       //your business code to deal with the content of the response from your http request
    }
```

Comment: None of the delegate methods you specify get called... :( I am doing <NSURLConnectionDelegate, NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate> for the delegate object's class

Comment: This kind of URL `https://[rest of URL]/[form name].asp?username=[my username]&password=[my password]` is a GET message, not POST.